# Capture a function call's arguments with sweet.js

Tags: javascript, macros, sweet.js

I'm trying to write a rule for capturing the expression and arguments of a function call with sweet.js.

Here's my current macro (that fails to match):

```
macro foo {
    rule {
        ( $fn:expr ($args ...) )
    } => {
        $fn("stuff", $args ...) // pushes "stuff" to the beginning of the arguments
    }
}
```

And some inputs and expected outputs:

```
foo(somefn("bar"))
```

should output:

```
somefn("stuff", "bar")
```

and

```
foo(console.log("bar"))
```

should output:

```
console.log("stuff", "bar")
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:expr` pattern class is greedy so `$fn:expr` is matching all of `somefn("bar")` (since that's an entire expression).

In the case, probably the easiest solution is to use ellipses:

```
macro foo {
    rule {
        ( $fn ... ($args ...) )
    } => {
        $fn ... ("stuff", $args ...) // pushes "stuff" to the beginning of the arguments
    }
}
```